# How to stop validating a form as soon as an error is found?

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form field with many constraints, and I want to stop checking them as soon as one fails. This should result in the user seeing only 1 error per field at a time.

How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

put the rules in a sequence, check each rule if one breaks return.

on client side you would be using javascript
on server side you would be using any language that your server supports

Comment: Yes I know how to program, but this is a Symfony2 question. Symfony2 comes with a very robust form component, and I would rather use that.

Comment: thank you andy, i'm sorry im new here... should i delete the answer?